# reconstruction error for PCA-analysis

Tags: pca

I am working on an assignment for school where they ask us to perform PCA-analysis on a data set consisting of 500 data points where each data point is of dimension $p=256$. You usually project your data set on the vector space spanned by the $q$ eigenvectors corresponding to the $q$ largest eigenvalues, so your $q$ of choice should be smaller than $p$. However, if I take $q=256$ and perform PCA to reconstruct the original mean of the data and then compute the RMSE between the original mean and the reconstructed mean , I obtain that the RMSE equals 0.3063. Why is this the case? Wouldn't you expect the RMSE to be equal to zero if you take $q=p$?

Comment: Side note: the A stands for ‘analysis’, so you don’t need to call it ‘PCA analysis’. That’s a case of [RAS syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome).

Comment: Without knowing the details, my first guess is that this is a numerical precision problem, i.e., a limitation of the fact that computers represent real numbers approximately with finite precision. But it’s also probably not a big enough problem to worry about.